# Select onChange link to value - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

How can I link to a `value` when selected `onChange` in a select box?

Looking to implement a `select` menu into **ReactJS** that links to the `value` `onChange`.

```
render() {
   return (
      <select onChange={() => {if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value}}>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        {pages.map(({ node: page })=> (
          <option key={page.id} value="{page.slug}">{page.title}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
}
```

This is getting the value (I believe) but I keep getting the error of `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

I have tried following the documents [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) as suggested in some answers yet I have not been able to get this working with my current code - see as follows the full Page.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import config from '../utils/siteConfig'

const PageCompany = ({data}) => {

  const {title,slug} = data.contentfulCompanyPage;
  const pages = data.allContentfulCompanyPage.edges;

  return(
    <Wrapper>
      <CompanyMenu>
        <div>
          <select onChange={() => {if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value}}>
            <option value="">Please select</option>
            {pages.map(({ node: page })=> (
              <option key={page.id} value="{page.slug}">{page.title}</option>
            ))}   
          </select>
        </div>
      </CompanyMenu>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}

export const companyQuery = graphql`
  query companyQuery($slug: String!) {
    contentfulCompanyPage(slug: {eq: $slug}) {
      title
      slug
      keywords
      description
      heroBg {
        sizes(maxWidth: 1500) {
          src
        }
      }
    }
    allContentfulCompanyPage(sort: {fields: [menuOrder], order: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default PageCompany
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making use of Global `window.location` property you can make a separate method `handleChange` like :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { }; // initialise state 

 // Make sure to bind handleChange or you can make use of arrow function

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    const targetValue = e.target.value;
// Then you can do whatever you want to do with the value 
    this.setState({
      [name]: targetValue
    });
```

**EDIT :**  In order to make use of `constructor` make sure you are defining components using `class` syntax like:

```
    import React , { Component } from 'react';

    class PageCompany extends Component { 
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = { }; // initialise state 
         this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
     }

    // Make sure class has a render method 

    render () {
     return ()  
    }
 }
```

And inside your `<Select>` You can reference it to `handleChange`

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
```

You can read more about onChange [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: Thank you @Aaquib. This is the closest I have gotten - however as soon as I select a `value` I get `ReferenceError: handleChange is not defined` on  `handleChange = (e) => {`. I have updated my question to include the full page code.

Comment: Updated my answer hope it will make things more clear

Comment: Thank you - I got that part already - the issue is whenever, however I try to add `constructor(props) {` it fails to compile.

Comment: Problem is as soon as I move the select box outside of this document into a component I lose my data from passing. I could map it again but for such a simple select box it seems there must be a way to do with what I have.

Comment: Updated my answer again , However if you want to make use of that data else where you need to set it using `setState` and then access it inside the other components  using `props`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll go see how to put the data elsewhere as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `event` param and then grab the value from the target of that event e.g.

```
onChange={(event) => this.setState({value: event.target.value})}
```

There's a great example [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).
Full code excerpt from linked docs:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cameck. I have tried following this document but I cannot get working with the current page template. Problem is as soon as I move the select box outside of this document into a `component` I lose my data from passing. I could map it again but for such a simple select box it seems there must be a way to do with what I have. I have updated my question to show the full file code. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @Darren, sorry that didn't solve your problem but it looks you solved it! :)